# GPU support error in cmake while configuring the darknet for YOLOv3 and YOLOv4

Tags: c, cmake, deep-learning, yolo, cmake-gui

I've been trying to set up the YOLOv3 with the darknet (according to this tutorial: https://youtu.be/saDipJR14Lc at 11:30). While configuring the darknet with CUDA support, CMake raised

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:156 (message):
  CUDA not found, please build explicitly with -DENABLE_CUDA=OFF if you do
  not want CUDA.
```

[image]

I looked at a bunch of GitHub and StackOverflow threads about this or any similar error message, but I haven't found any solution yet that works. By the way, when I check my CUDA version (11.2) in cmd (I'm on Windows), the version shows up correctly.

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages **images** which just represent a text. Instead we expect the **text** itself to be pasted into the question post. This can be done at least for the error message about the CUDA. See [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.

Comment: I tried many different ideas. Finally, I installed CUDA 12, which solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When installing Cuda, there was an error that the VS version is not suitable. Reinstalled from 2022 to 2019